# windows was not able to complete the format

Tags: usb-flash-drive

i have 16 gb flash drive and whenever i try to format it, the error "windows was not able to complete the format". so i tried formatting it via disk management but it still didn't work and when i tried using diskpart it encounters an error saying "the request could not be performed because of an I/O device error" and yes i did run as admin when using the cmd. Any tips on fixing this thing ?

Comment: it was still working yesterday and i formatted it hundreds of times already until this day

Comment: Yeah - they do that:/ I go through literally hundreds of them for work. If they start to play up, bin them. Not worth the effort. ..which of course leads to the inevitable "Never, ever, keep the only copy of any data on one. They break without warning."

Comment: it only contains anime episodes anyway not much of a disappointment and i have a 32gb flash drive and external hard drive. i was planning to give it to a friend that's why i'm trying to revive it . thanks tho, guess it's end of the line for this little guy

Answer (score 0):

1. Hook up the drive on your PC and go to the 'Run' (or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) menu and type `cmd.exe`
2. Type `DISKPART`
3. Type `LIST DISK`
4. `select disk #` (the number from the list) eg. if the disk is number 7, type 
   ´SELECT DISK 7`
5. type `CLEAN` Voila the disk Partition has been removed.
6. Right click on my computer, select 'Manage' and then 'Disk Management'. The drive will then ask you to initialize, say yes.
7. Right click on the Unallocated space and select "New Partition…"
8. Create the new partition as an NTFS format with the “quick format” box ticked (otherwise it’ll take hours). Name this drive  as you wish.